# How to install cx_Oracle in Python Anaconda

Tags: python, cx-oracle, anaconda3

I am trying to install cx_Oracle in python and Anaconda platforms but I couldn't able to install. I am getting following error:

> **Traceback (most recent call last):   File "setup.py", line 132, in 
> raise DistutilsSetupError("cannot locate an Oracle software " \ distutils.errors.DistutilsSetupError: cannot locate an Oracle software
> installation**

I tried to install all dependencies like Oracle basic light package, Visual studio and ODBC light packages... and I have added paths in to ENV variables but still I am getting error.

Please help me out from this.
Thanks in advance

Comment: **1.** Open Anaconda.
**2.** Select Environments in the left hand pane below home.
**3.** Just to the right of where you selected and below the "search environments" bar, you should see base(root). Click on it.
**4.** A triangle pointing right should appear, click on it an select "open terminal"
**5.** Use the regular pip install command here( ***pip install cx_Oracle*** ).

Comment: Hi Barbaros I tried but getting this error WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x0000023B28500550>, 'Connection to pypi.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/cx-oracle/

Comment: Maybe you need to use a proxy to traverse a firewall?  The cx_Oracle install doc gives the pip option for that.